# RTX 2070 I can't open Blender

Tags: gpu

I've installed another GPU card RTX 2070 in the second PCIex16 motherboard slot. Not a SLI connection. Both cards were previously installed in this machine separately with the drivers updated for both. Blender doesn't want to open. A video card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher required. Why am I getting this message? TY.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't update anything because I use a laptop. You can still open Blender 2.79, and if you can't update your drivers to 3.3 or higher, then you must use 2.79.

Comment: I would like to make it work in 2.81. Recently started in Blender and never used 2.79. Hopefully someone out there knows the trick.

Comment: Make sure that you start Blender with one of your dedicated GPUs (Nvidia Control Panel) instead of the integrated GPU in your CPU. Alternatively, if you want to use your integrated GPU, check if it fulfills the minimum requirements for Blender 2.8x and try to update the graphics driver from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: I have a Ryzen 5 2600x cpu with no integrated video chip. I always start the computer with the monitor plugged in my RTX 2070. If I use only one card everything is fine and Blender opens without problems. If I install another RTX 2070 in the second PCIe 16 slot Blender doesn’t open with the message for OpenGL 3.3 or higher. Why is this happening? Motherboard B450 Tomahawk

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I made it work. I had to flash the bios. If you are like me playing with the settings all the time you need to reset the bios by taking out the little round battery on the mobo. Depending on your mobo, the flash reset button next to the usb slots on the mobo didn't work for me, it might work for you. After that blender will open and both cards are seen in Cuda and Optix. Indeed there is some work but I'm pretty happy with the result right now. However render time is not cut in half though. More like 35% less with two cards.